# How to set VS Code extension Intelephense for PHP 8?

Tags: php, laragon, php-8, intelephense

I would like to set my bought Visual Studio Code extension to use PHP 8 version for it's "intelisense" functionality.

Checking `defaultSettings.json` for 'intelephense' search query gives lots of hits, but only one stands out to me for upgrading to PHP 8:

```json
// A semver compatible string that represents the target PHP version. Used for providing version appropriate suggestions and diagnostics. PHP 5.3.0 and greater supported.
"intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "7.4.0",
```

This should probably be changed in Workspace Settings `.vscode\settings.json` to

```json
"intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1.0-dev", // or would "8.0.0" be better?
```

Is there anything else that needs to be changed?

I am using Laragon for local development with PHP 7.2 and 8.0 installed. Staging and production servers use PHP 8.0.

Comment: https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1566 - Written 6 hours ago: _"PHP 8 will be supported in the 1.6 release"_

Comment: Thank you for pointing out where I should check first 