# PHP8 VS Code: Compiler throws error when using union types

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to code PHP8. I wanted to try the strict types `declare(strict_types=1)`.

When using single types, everything is fine:

```
function doSomething(int $value): ?float
{
    if ($value === null) return null;
    return round($value, 3);
}
```

When using union types, the compiler throws errors:

```
function doSomething(int|string $value): ?float
{
    if ($value === null) return null;
    return round($value, 3);
}
```

Errors:

```
'VariableName' expected
')' expected
'{' expected
Unexpected '|'
';'
...
```

I disabled the PHP language features and I am using the `PHP Intelephense v1.8.0` extension.

Comment: `$value` cannot be `null`, because the type of `$value` is `int` or `string` (https://3v4l.org/e2kuH#v8.0.15). That said, the error says that the parser doesn't know PHP8 and union types (https://3v4l.org/v4OJf).

Comment: So there is currently no PHP VS code extension what supports / works with PHP8?

Comment: See also this [interesting comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475596/how-to-set-vs-code-extension-intelephense-for-php-8#comment115758080_65475596), and [this one](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1566).

Comment: You make a lot of emphasis in the error being thrown by compiler but that's shown by your IDEs linter (PHP Intelephense). The actual PHP error is "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: round(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given" ([demo](https://3v4l.org/8Xv8g#v8.1.2)) because [round()](https://php.net/round) doesn't accept strings.

Comment: Also, have you configured PHP Intelephense to use PHP/8.1 syntax? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621681/how-do-i-correct-syntax-highlight-in-vs-code-for-php-8-1-enum-class/70621895#70621895